# Considering transforms in torchaudio, is window length etc. in audio frames or milliseconds

Tags: pytorch, audio-processing

I am preprocessing audio recordings using torchaudio. The [documentation](https://pytorch.org/audio/transforms.html#melspectrogram) lists `win_length (int) – Window size. (Default: n_fft)` Does this value, which defaults to 400, represent the window length in frames or milliseconds?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `n_fft` variable is used in the `Spectrogram` class. And it's [forward function documentation](https://pytorch.org/audio/transforms.html#torchaudio.transforms.Spectrogram.forward) mentions

> where `n_fft` is the number of Fourier bins